# Rails - modifying/duplicating default "show"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

Is there anyway that I can modify the behavior of the default "show" ?

Currently when a user clicks on a button the main site

```
<%= link_to "ADD TO CART", product, {:class => "btn btn-primary", :target => '_blank', :method => "get"} %>
```

The user will be automatically redirected to a page with the appropriate information.

Now I'm trying to create a slightly different page (mobile friendly) and I've created a mobile_show page that works if I access it directly.

My question is how should I modify the link_to so that it points to `/mobile/products/id` instead of the current `products/id` ?

Update (Extra info):

In products_controller.rb`

```
  # GET /mobile
  # GET /mobile.json
  def mobile
    @products = Product.current

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # mobile.html.erb
      #format.json { render json: @products }
    end
  end`

  # GET /mobile/products/1
  # GET /mobile/products/1.json
  def mobile_show
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
    @product.update_attribute(:is_active, false)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # mobile_show.html.erb
      #format.json { render json: @product }
    end
  end
```

In routes.rb

```
  match '/mobile' => 'products#mobile'
  match '/cashback' => 'products#cashback'
  match '/mobile/products/:id' => 'products#mobile_show'
```

p/s: I'm very new to rails and web-development in general

Comment: that actually depends on your routes.  how did you add support for `/mobile` namespace?

Comment: @jvnill Not really sure what you mean but I've updated the main post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should actually create a namespace or controller specifically for mobile so it doesn't break REST
eg

app/controllers/mobile/products_controller.rb

or

app/controllers/mobile_products_controller.rb

But to use your method, you might want to add a name to your route so you can use it

```
match '/mobile' => 'products#mobile', :as => "mobile"
```

Then change your

```
<%= link_to "ADD TO CART", mobile_path, {:class => "btn btn-primary", :target => '_blank', :method => "get"} %>
```

Answer (score 0):

based on your existing routes, you can change your route to

```
match '/mobile/products/:id' => 'products#mobile_show', as: :mobile_product
```

then in your view

```
<%= link_to "ADD TO CART", mobile_product_path(product), {:class => "btn btn-primary", :target => '_blank', :method => "get"} %>
```

UPDATE: is it good practice?

This actually depends on what you want to achieve.  If you want to create a mobile version for your app, I suggest you look at a responsive ui.  If that is not possible, the right way to handle this is to create a different set of controllers that will handle mobile requests.
These controllers should be placed under a different namespace.

```
namespace :mobile do
  resources :products
end
```

This would expect you to have an `app/controllers/mobile/products_controller.rb` and handle mobile requests here.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. But is this the proper way to do it? (good/generally accepted)